# How to restart (or stop or heck even start) the nfs client service on ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, nfs

The /etc/init.d/nfs-common file has been removed.

There is no NFS service utility.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this:

[NFSv4Howto - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto)

> ... and restart nfs-common.
>
> ```
> service idmapd restart
> ```

So, apparently, `nfs-common` is now known as `idmapd`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `initctl start <service-name>`.

Answer (score -1):

Try completely removing the package using `apt-get --purge remove <package>` and reinstalling.