# NFS Server/Client administration of multiple machines through a GUI

Tags: linux, nfs

I want to share folders between PCs on a local network, which may have different Linuxes installed (or booted from a USB key). Thus, I do *not* want to count on the sharing capabilities of a given file manager (like `nautilus`), because some PCs on the network may have a given file manager – some may not!

Some of these PCs on the local network may have broken keyboards, and have only a mouse available – and it would be quite tedious to type all the needed commands using the mouse on a virtual keyboard.

I am aware that there exists `system-config-nfs` for Fedora (from [CentOS / Redhat: Setup NFS v4.0 File Server (cyberciti.biz)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-fedora-rhel-nfs-v4-configuration/)):

[image: system-config-nfs]

... but:

- This looks like only covering Server setup – I want to set up the Client as well
- I often use Ubuntu, and it doesn't look like `system-config-nfs` is present in Ubuntu repositories (not sure if a compatible package may be present in Debian repositories, though)

If `system-config-nfs` cannot configure clients, is there any other way I can manage both NFS Server and Client-side configuration on multiple machines through a GUI - without connecting to each individually from the command line?

---

EDIT: There is (so far): [nfs-lan](https://superuser.com/questions/636562/nfs-server-client-administration-of-multiple-machines-through-a-gui/1118201#1118201) for Gnome, and [webmin](https://superuser.com/questions/636562/nfs-server-client-administration-of-multiple-machines-through-a-gui/637468#637468) via browser

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did manage to find one tool, that offers a GUI for both server and client NFS setup, and it is [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/), a "web-based interface for system administration for Unix". Here are some clickable screenshots:

**Server setup GUI screenshots**

(s0) [image: server_00]
(s1) [image: server_01]
(s2a) [image: server_02a]
(s2b) [image: server_02b]
(s3) [image: server_03]

**Client setup GUI screenshots**

(c0) [image: client_00]
(c1) [image: client_01]
(c2a) [image: client_02a]
(c2b) [image: client_02b]
(c3) [image: client_03]

However:

- Being web-based, it demands that a JavaScript (and SSL) capable browser is installed on both client and server computers
- Being a system-administration tool, it contains a lot more options than just NFS setup, so it can be difficult to get an instant overview of it

Also, note I don't know enough about NFS to setup proper security, which is why my goal is to setup shares for a local network quickly with no security; do a job; and then tear down the NFS sharing just as quickly. This and the above two reasons are why I was hoping I could track down a GUI that is simpler (e.g. written in Python/Tkinter, and for NFS only); but at least `webmin` offers *both* server *and* client GUI setup, which is the most important for me to begin with (so I'm spared of dealing with NFS internals as much as possible).

I've made a test on Ubuntu 11.04 PC (proper install) as server and Ubuntu 12.04 PC (live image based on Mini Remix ISO) as client; and besides the installation of `webmin` and dependencies being not exactly trivial - it's also not exactly trivial to use it to setup NFS. Which is why I will take the liberty to post my notes here, in a sort of a tutorial format - hope that's OK.

---

First, the usage. Note that in NFS (`webmin`?) parlance:

- The PC sharing a folder on the network is the *server*, and its shared folder is known as an "*NFS Export*"

  - All folders thus exported, in case of NFS 4, will be set under one (or more) "NFSv4 Pseudofilesystem" root(s)
- The PC accessing a network shared folder is the *client*, and the accessed network folder is known as an "*NFS Share*"

### Server NFS sharing setup

- Create a directory to be shared, e.g. `/tmp/sharetest`
- In `webmin`, visit `https://127.0.0.1:10000`, and login with an account that is a sudoer
- After login, expand the "Networking" node in the left frame (requires JavaScript) (s0) and click on "Networking"/"NFS Exports" (s1)
- On the subsequent "NFS Exports" page, click on "Add a new export" (s1)
- On the next page, "Create Export", keep "NFS version" on 4, and click on the `...` button at the "Directory to export" field, and navigate to (with doubleclick) - and choose - the `/tmp/sharetest` directory (s2a)
- Back on the "Create Export" page, you may want to set "Read-only?" to "No", and otherwise keep the defaults - finally click on "Create" button (s2b)
- The "NFS Exports" page is shown again, with two new entries, `/export` and `/export/sharetest` (s3)
- Note here that `/export` is an automatically created "NFSv4 Pseudofilesystem" root

  - If creating additional NFS exports, they can either use this pseudofilesystem root - or ask for a creation of a new one

Note that here, if you want to edit the NFS exports, there may be buggy GUI behavior for NFS v4 - for which I've filed a bug: [Webmin / Bugs / #4286 NFS v4 exports do not persist as v4 upon edit - they revert to v3; and NFS Version help missing](https://sourceforge.net/p/webadmin/bugs/4286/). The changes made to the NFS exports here, are reflected in the file `/etc/exports`. Note that setting "Read-only?" (which is the `rw` option in `/etc/exports`) to "No" is *not* enough to allow the clients to write in the directory - you must *also* make `/tmp/sharetest` world writable, using `chmod 777` (see ref [3]); also note that files written by clients will preserve the writers' uids - you should check whether that introduces problems for you.

### Client NFS sharing setup

- Create a local directory which will be mapped to the network share, e.g. `/tmp/nfsshare`
- In `webmin`, visit `https://127.0.0.1:10000`, and login with an account that is a sudoer
- After login, expand the "System" node in the left frame (requires JavaScript) (c0) and click on "System"/"Disk and Network Filesystems" (c1)
- On the subsequent "Disk and Network Filesystems" page, select "Network Filesystem v4 (nfs4)" from the dropdown, and click on the "Add mount" button (c1)
- On the next page, "Create Mount", click on the "..." button next to the "NFS Hostname" textfield (which initially says "mount") (c2a:1)
- A new window "Choose NFS Server" will popup; the NFS server should be autodetected if it is running - so click on the link under "IP Address" column (c2a:2), which will populate the "NFS Hostname" textfield with the corresponding "Hostname"; and close the popup
- Back on the "Create Mount" page, click on the "..." button next to the "NFS Directory" textfield (c2a:3)
- A new window "Choose NFS Directory" will popup; the exports should be listed - however note that "For an NFSv4 mount, you should select '/'" - so click on `/` link under "Directory" column (c2a:4), which will populate the "NFS Directory" textfield with the corresponding "Directory" - or just close the popup to leave the default `/` unchanged
- Back on the "Create Mount" page, click on the "..." button next to the "Mounted As" textfield (c2a:5)
- A new window "Choose Directory" will popup;  navigate to and choose the `/tmp/nfsshare` directory, and click OK (c2a:6)
- Back on the "Create Mount" page, you may want to set "Read-only?" to "No", and otherwise keep the defaults - finally click on "Create" button (c2b)
- Once back on the "Disk and Network Filesystems", you should see the new share being listed in the table (c3)
- To check that everything is OK, you can try listing the `/tmp/nfsshare` directory (c3) - or writing into the `/tmp/nfsshare/sharetest` directory

Note that, if by accident you close down the NFS server while the clients are still running, you may be left with "dangling" shares; in this case, the command `sudo umount -lf ...` seems to help:

```
ubuntu@Client:~$ mount
...
Server-eth0:/export/sharetest on /tmp/nfsshare type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.1.42)
Server-eth0:/export/sharetest on /tmp/.webmin/402201_1_save_mount.cgi type nfs (rw,vers=4,addr=192.168.1.42,clientaddr=192.168.1.77)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
Server-eth0:/export/sharetest on /tmp/.webmin/303774_1_save_mount.cgi type nfs (rw,vers=4,addr=192.168.1.42,clientaddr=192.168.1.77)

ubuntu@Client:~$ sudo umount -lf /tmp/.webmin/402201_1_save_mount.cgi
ubuntu@Client:~$ sudo umount -lf /tmp/.webmin/303774_1_save_mount.cgi

ubuntu@Client:~$ mount
...
Server-eth0:/export/sharetest on /tmp/nfsshare type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.1.42)
```

---

### `webmin` install on Server (Ubuntu 11.04 proper install)

```
suser@Server:tmp$ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server  # also pulls nfs-common
suser@Server:tmp$ sudo apt-get install libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
suser@Server:tmp$ wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.580_all.deb
suser@Server:tmp$ sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.580_all.deb
```

**Stop services**

```
sudo service nfs-kernel-server stop   # also clears /etc/exports
sudo service idmapd stop
sudo service portmap stop
sudo service webmin stop    # also: sudo /etc/webmin/stop
```

**Uninstall**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nfs-kernel-server libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl && sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
# sudo dpkg -r webmin # not needed; the previous command should remove webmin by dependency
```

### `webmin` install on Client (Ubuntu 12.04 live image)

```
ubuntu@Client:~$ sudo nano /ets/apt/sources.list  # uncomment `universe` repositories, and save
ubuntu@Client:~$ sudo apt-get update
ubuntu@Client:~$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common  # "initctl: Unknown job: portmap / statd / gssd / idmapd" here
ubuntu@Client:~$ sudo initctl reload-configuration
ubuntu@Client:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall rpcbind nfs-common # now "portmap ... idmapd start/running,"
ubuntu@Client:~$ sudo apt-get install libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
ubuntu@Client:~$ wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.580_all.deb
ubuntu@Client:~$ sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.580_all.deb
```

**Stop services**

```
sudo service idmapd stop
sudo service portmap stop
sudo service webmin stop    # also: sudo /etc/webmin/stop
```

**Uninstall**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nfs-common libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl && sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
# sudo dpkg -r webmin # not needed; the previous command should remove webmin by dependency
```

Installation notes:

- `webmin` is not available in Ubuntu repositories; it can be installed through a `.deb` package from the webmin site

  - downloading an older .deb like here is not a problem, because webmin allows for updates directly from its web interface
- Nearly all `webmin` dependencies are available in the Ubuntu `main` repositories, except for `libauthen-pam-perl`, which is in the `universe` repositories
- Ubuntu live images have the `universe` repositories *disabled by default*; so they must first be enabled by uncommenting the respective entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, followed by `sudo apt-get update` (*else `E: Unable to locate package libauthen-pam-perl` / `E: Package 'libauthen-pam-perl' has no installation candidate` occurs*)
- Ubuntu live images apparently "did not rescan the /etc/init directory automatically" (ref. [1]), so they need a manual call to `initctl reload-configuration` (*else `initctl: Unknown job: portmap` occurs*)

  - `initclt` needs to be called with `sudo` (*else `initctl: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; ...` occurs*)
- After installing `nfs-common`, a *service* called `portmap` exists on both 11.04 and 12.04,

  - ... however, 11.04 has a *package* called `portmap` - while 12.04 replaces it with a package `rpcbind` (*message `Note, selecting 'rpcbind' instead of 'portmap'` occurs*)
  - What used to be known as `nfs-common` service in older Ubuntus, is now (apparently) called `idmapd` (ref. [2])
- There is no `nfs` service (may be found in older tutorials) installed anywhere - neither on server nor on client
- `libio-pty-perl` may already be present on your system, if you have installed e.g. `moreutils`; if so, be careful not to refer to it in the above uninstall commands (same goes for other dependencies)

References:

1. [Bug #857406 “Failed to install rpcbind” (#3) : Bugs : “linux” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/857406)
2. [How to restart (or stop or heck even start) the nfs client service on ubuntu 9.10? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/123659/how-to-restart-or-stop-or-heck-even-start-the-nfs-client-service-on-ubuntu-9-1/636616#636616)
3. [[SOLVED] write permission for users on NFS folder](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/write-permission-for-users-on-nfs-folder-852800/)
4. [Ubuntu Server: NFS Client and Server configuration using Webmin](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Configure-NFS.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, via [[gnome] Nautilus NFS integration](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1492067) I found `nfs-lan` (http://nfs-lan.sevka.info/); this is what I did to install it on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (which has Gnome 3):

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-nautilus-3.0
sudo apt-get install python-nautilus nfs-kernel-server autofs
# wget "http://nfs-lan.sevka.info/downloads/nfs_lan-1.0.deb?attredirects=0&d=1"
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/nfs_lan-1.0.deb
```

... and then, to configure:

```
sudo nano /etc/auto.master
# add: /net -hosts --timeout=60
# then save file, exit
sudo service autofs restart
```

Now, to browse in Nautilus, you have to first type `/` so as to open the address bar, and then type `net/` - then press enter and you can browse NFS network:

[image: net2]

Otherwise, for sharing, there will be a right click option for Nautilus folders:

[image: net3]